# Button gives unintended effects on click of the button

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml, wpf-controls

Folks, I am very new to WPF ad started learning it with Sam's E-book. I just tried the same code given in the book as follows

```
<Window x:Class="wpfTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Button Background="Black">
        <Button.Content>
            <Ellipse Width="103" Height="107" Fill="Yellow" />
        </Button.Content>
    </Button>
</Window>
```

Pity thing is, when I once click on the button, it starts blinking slowly, giving the black background as specified and also white/blue background and it never stops. I dont know why the default behavior is like that as I haven't mentioned any effects/styles/triggers/animations. :( Do anybody can please guide me and rectify it. Please make me understand the reason behind the same too :(

Comment: Can you give a code example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: <Window x:Class="wpfTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Button Background="Black">
        <Button.Content>
        <Ellipse Width="103"
Height="107"
Fill="Yellow" />
        </Button.Content>
    </Button>
</Window>

Comment: Steve, very sorry, I wrote this code above as well, duno why this dint appeared :(

Comment: The code you've provided is not the problem. Are you sure you're compiling/running the right solution?

Comment: @KshitijMehta: I do compile the right code. Don't you get the same effetcs once you click ? I don't get the same effect before click event. It blinks only after first click event.

Comment: Seems that this is system default animation. You could disable it by writing your own style without this animation.

Comment: Indians please refrain from giving comments/links unless you are very sure about the problem and solution. Thank you, no offence meant

Comment: I have just tried it using your xaml, and I am seeing the same thing. It carries on flashing due to the mouseover/mousedown events, and continues until it looses focus

Comment: @Dantix: You are very true. I really find it awkward though, although at the same time, I find it interesting too :P Gives me great UI effets without me doing anything hehe ...Attractive ;) But I am wondering on why they gave such default animation :(

Comment: @stevethethread: No no, that flashing occurs or starts only on first click event and it keeps on continuing. Mouseover/down after that flash starts doesnt make any difference which is what I observed. As you rightly said, yes before the flash starts(Or click event) the mouseover/down gives this effect

Comment: @stevethethread: You are absolutely right about the point on when this flashing stops, i.e on lose of focus... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Window x:Class="testwpf.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="BorderlessButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border Name="border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter Name="content" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                  Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                  RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                  SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                  VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Button Style="{DynamicResource BorderlessButton}">
        <Button.Content>
            <Ellipse Width="103" Height="107" Fill="Yellow" />
        </Button.Content>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

Custom style disables system animation animation. Code from [here](http://gregandora.wordpress.com/2011/02/06/wpf-minimal-button-styling/)

Comment: Hey Dantix, perfect, I appreciate it, I tried this code it is superb, thank you :) But never thought MS would give such an unintended behaviour by default. I don't see a good reason for using such effects by default

Comment: @Divine The point of the animation is so the user can see what button they clicked last. They used to do that awkward border thing, and now they do the animation highlight. Just another change in the UI.

Comment: @Divine No problem. It's understandably confusing when you have a single button on your page. At first I didn't know what was going on either :P

Comment: @steveg89: :) :) Yeup right, it was shocking to me when I tried this first example as I am newbie :) Cheers to you buddy :) Thank you... :)